# Can Upstart be installed side-by-side with other init script?

Tags: upstart

Can upstart be installed along side other init system? Upstart is quite handy in creating a daemon script written in PHP as it can respawn process. Unfortunately, it will be replace with systemd in the next ubuntu release. And how about other Linux distro? Centos, RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Upstart can be installed alongside system V init scripts. But, I would recommend using other process monitoring tools like "monit" over upstart because of the following reasons:

a. upstart scripts are too low level.
b. All debian systems(includes ubuntu) will be moving away from upstart back to systemd. [Reference here.](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316)